# Dygraph not defined in meteorjs client side

Tags: javascript, meteor, dygraphs

I am using dygraphjs (with meteorjs, because of easy integration with mongo) for visualization. I have included dygraph-combined.js in client/lib folder. Now I can see that in view-source dygraphjs is included before my client js, but still giving error 'Dygraph is not defined'.

Code in client.js

```
Template.body.onRendered(function() {
g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById('graph'),
  data1,
  {
    labels: seriesName,
    legend: 'always',
    animatedZooms: false,
    title: 'Dygraph',
    zoomCallback: function(minDate, maxDate, yRange){
      min = minDate;
      max = maxDate;
      // zoomData(min, max, yRange, data);
      this.updateOptions({
        dateWindow: null,
        valueRange: null
      });
    },
    underlayCallback: function(canvas, area, g){
      var bottom_left = g.toDomCoords(min, -20);
      var top_right = g.toDomCoords(max, +20);

      var left = bottom_left[0];
      var right = top_right[0];

      canvas.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 102, 1.0)";
      canvas.fillRect(left, area.y, right - left, area.h);
    }
  }
);
g.ready(function() {
  g.setAnnotations(
      [{
          series: 'A',
          x: 123,
          shortText: "pre wash",
          width: 100,
          height: 20,
          tickHeight: 220,
          attachAtBottom: true,
          cssClass: 'test-annot'
      }]
  );
});
});
```

How can I load dygraph early and use in client side js of meteor?

Comment: I got it working by putting dygraph-combined.js in client/compatibility folder. waiting if there is other better way.